# How exactly do I play Minecraft with 2 people?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I want to play Minecraft with my friend.

I bought it off the Xbox 360 store, But I can only seem to play single player.

How do I play with 2 people?

Comment: Do you mean local (splitscreen) or online?

Answer (score 2):

There are all kinds of servers that you can join via your Minecraft client on your X360. Check out some of the posts here. You and your friend would need to join the same multiplayer server simultaneously to hang out together.

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-xbox-360-edition/mcx360-multiplayer/mcx360-servers

If you're looking to just start a local, split-screen type of multiplayer game, you'd need to have an HD screen (something displaying in full HD, 1920x1080 AKA 1080p), grab a second controller and have your second player sign in while a local world is running. Voila!

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out good ways to play the game in multiplayer.

## Xbox Live

Fist you need to get Xbox live and Gold to do this. Then find any player and invite them the friends list and the game itself. If you need to find a player quickly, you can ask on websites if anyone wants to play with him. If you already have friends who want to play with you, type in the nametags they give you and invite them to friends list and the game.

## Offline [Only works if you already have friends who play the game withs you. Also must be with you together.]

You can do splitscreen. To do this, make sure you have more than one controller. When you're in the game, connect the other controllers by holding the Xbox symbol on them. They should connect, but no yet ready for gameplay. So create profiles for your friends and then you're ready. 2 players only.

## Servers

You can connect to servers, where you can play in a world with lots of other plays, chat, play minigames, and more! First you need to be on Live, second, go to this website: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-xbox-360-edition/mcx360-multiplayer/mcx360-servers